# Put text to Label - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, binding, label, xamarin.forms

How do I put new text to a label in xamarin.forms?

If I have this in XAML:

```
 <Label   Text="{Binding Nombre}" Font="Bold,16" x:Name="tNombre"  TextColor="{StaticResource ColorBlanco}" Style="{StaticResource TextAligment}"/>
```

But to put the new text: how is it in code?: What do I have to use?... I am new in this.

Comment: Can you add to your question the code from the c# part of the view?

Comment: In page use tNombre.Text = "someText";

Comment: Try to do it the way you say @mww , but I get an error :

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Label you show is bound to the Nombre field.

```
<Label   Text="{Binding Nombre}"
```

As long as the class you are bound to implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface changing the value for Nombre in the class you are bound to should update the UI

Comment: Can you please update your answer to be more clear. How could I implement INotifyPropertyChanged